# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced

Tags: python, numpy, nan, missing-data, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to convert a csv into numpy array. In the numpy array, I am replacing few elements with NaN. Then, I wanted to find the indices of the NaN elements in the numpy array. The code is :

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plyt
import numpy as np

filename = 'wether.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename,header = None )

list = df.values.tolist()
labels = list[0]
wether_list = list[1:]

year = []
month = []
day = []
max_temp = []

for i in wether_list:
    year.append(i[1])
    month.append(i[2])
    day.append(i[3])
    max_temp.append(i[5])

mid = len(max_temp) // 2
temps = np.array(max_temp[mid:])
temps[np.where(np.array(temps) == -99.9)] = np.nan
plyt.plot(temps,marker = '.',color = 'black',linestyle = 'none')
# plyt.show()

print(np.where(np.isnan(temps))[0])
# print(len(pd.isnull(np.array(temps))))
```

When I execute this, I am getting a warning and an error. The warning is :

```
    wether.py:26: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  temps[np.where(np.array(temps) == -99.9)] = np.nan
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wether.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(np.where(np.isnan(temps))[0])
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

This is a part of the dataset which I am using:

```
83168,2014,9,7,0.00000,89.00000,78.00000, 83.50000
83168,2014,9,22,1.62000,90.00000,72.00000, 81.00000
83168,2014,9,23,0.50000,87.00000,74.00000, 80.50000
83168,2014,9,24,0.35000,82.00000,73.00000, 77.50000
83168,2014,9,25,0.60000,85.00000,75.00000, 80.00000
83168,2014,9,26,0.76000,89.00000,77.00000, 83.00000
83168,2014,9,27,0.00000,89.00000,79.00000, 84.00000
83168,2014,9,28,0.00000,90.00000,81.00000, 85.50000
83168,2014,9,29,0.00000,90.00000,79.00000, 84.50000
83168,2014,9,30,0.50000,89.00000,75.00000, 82.00000
83168,2014,10,1,0.02000,91.00000,75.00000, 83.00000
83168,2014,10,2,0.03000,93.00000,77.00000, 85.00000
83168,2014,10,3,1.40000,93.00000,75.00000, 84.00000
83168,2014,10,4,0.06000,89.00000,75.00000, 82.00000
83168,2014,10,5,0.22000,91.00000,68.00000, 79.50000
83168,2014,10,6,0.00000,84.00000,68.00000, 76.00000
83168,2014,10,7,0.17000,85.00000,73.00000, 79.00000
83168,2014,10,8,0.06000,84.00000,73.00000, 78.50000
83168,2014,10,9,0.00000,87.00000,73.00000, 80.00000
83168,2014,10,10,0.00000,88.00000,80.00000, 84.00000
83168,2014,10,11,0.00000,87.00000,80.00000, 83.50000
83168,2014,10,12,0.00000,88.00000,80.00000, 84.00000
83168,2014,10,13,0.00000,88.00000,81.00000, 84.50000
83168,2014,10,14,0.04000,88.00000,77.00000, 82.50000
83168,2014,10,15,0.00000,88.00000,77.00000, 82.50000
83168,2014,10,16,0.09000,89.00000,72.00000, 80.50000
83168,2014,10,17,0.00000,85.00000,67.00000, 76.00000
83168,2014,10,18,0.00000,84.00000,65.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,10,19,0.00000,84.00000,65.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,10,20,0.00000,85.00000,69.00000, 77.00000
83168,2014,10,21,0.77000,87.00000,76.00000, 81.50000
83168,2014,10,22,0.69000,81.00000,71.00000, 76.00000
83168,2014,10,23,0.31000,82.00000,72.00000, 77.00000
83168,2014,10,24,0.71000,79.00000,73.00000, 76.00000
83168,2014,10,25,0.00000,81.00000,68.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,10,26,0.00000,82.00000,67.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,10,27,0.00000,83.00000,64.00000, 73.50000
83168,2014,10,28,0.00000,83.00000,66.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,10,29,0.03000,86.00000,76.00000, 81.00000
83168,2014,10,30,0.00000,85.00000,69.00000, 77.00000
83168,2014,10,31,0.00000,85.00000,69.00000, 77.00000
83168,2014,11,1,0.00000,86.00000,59.00000, 72.50000
83168,2014,11,2,0.00000,77.00000,52.00000, 64.50000
83168,2014,11,3,0.00000,70.00000,52.00000, 61.00000
83168,2014,11,4,0.00000,77.00000,59.00000, 68.00000
83168,2014,11,5,0.02000,79.00000,73.00000, 76.00000
83168,2014,11,6,0.02000,82.00000,75.00000, 78.50000
83168,2014,11,7,0.00000,83.00000,66.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,11,8,0.00000,84.00000,65.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,11,9,0.00000,84.00000,65.00000, 74.50000
83168,2014,11,10,1.20000,72.00000,65.00000, 68.50000
83168,2014,11,11,0.08000,77.00000,61.00000, 69.00000
83168,2014,11,12,0.00000,80.00000,61.00000, 70.50000
83168,2014,11,13,0.00000,83.00000,63.00000, 73.00000
83168,2014,11,14,0.00000,83.00000,65.00000, 74.00000
83168,2014,11,15,0.00000,82.00000,64.00000, 73.00000
83168,2014,11,16,0.00000,83.00000,64.00000, 73.50000
83168,2014,11,17,0.07000,84.00000,64.00000, 74.00000
83168,2014,11,18,0.00000,86.00000,71.00000, 78.50000
83168,2014,11,19,0.57000,78.00000,55.00000, 66.50000
83168,2014,11,20,0.05000,72.00000,56.00000, 64.00000
83168,2014,11,21,0.05000,77.00000,63.00000, 70.00000
83168,2014,11,22,0.22000,77.00000,69.00000, 73.00000
83168,2014,11,23,0.06000,79.00000,76.00000, 77.50000
83168,2014,11,24,0.02000,84.00000,78.00000, 81.00000
83168,2014,11,25,0.00000,86.00000,78.00000, 82.00000
83168,2014,11,26,0.07000,85.00000,77.00000, 81.00000
83168,2014,11,27,0.21000,82.00000,55.00000, 68.50000
83168,2014,11,28,0.00000,73.00000,53.00000, 63.00000
83168,2015,1,8,0.00000,80.00000,57.00000,
83168,2015,1,9,0.05000,72.00000,56.00000,
83168,2015,1,10,0.00000,72.00000,57.00000,
83168,2015,1,11,0.00000,80.00000,57.00000,
83168,2015,1,12,0.05000,80.00000,59.00000,
83168,2015,1,13,0.85000,81.00000,69.00000,
83168,2015,1,14,0.05000,81.00000,68.00000,
83168,2015,1,15,0.00000,81.00000,64.00000,
83168,2015,1,16,0.00000,78.00000,63.00000,
83168,2015,1,17,0.00000,73.00000,55.00000,
83168,2015,1,18,0.00000,76.00000,55.00000,
83168,2015,1,19,0.00000,78.00000,55.00000,
83168,2015,1,20,0.00000,75.00000,56.00000,
83168,2015,1,21,0.02000,73.00000,65.00000,
83168,2015,1,22,0.00000,80.00000,64.00000,
83168,2015,1,23,0.00000,80.00000,71.00000,
83168,2015,1,24,0.00000,79.00000,72.00000,
83168,2015,1,25,0.00000,79.00000,49.00000,
83168,2015,1,26,0.00000,79.00000,49.00000,
83168,2015,1,27,0.10000,75.00000,53.00000,
83168,2015,1,28,0.00000,68.00000,53.00000,
83168,2015,1,29,0.00000,69.00000,53.00000,
83168,2015,1,30,0.00000,72.00000,60.00000,
83168,2015,1,31,0.00000,76.00000,58.00000,
83168,2015,2,1,0.00000,76.00000,58.00000,
83168,2015,2,2,0.05000,77.00000,58.00000,
83168,2015,2,3,0.00000,84.00000,56.00000,
83168,2015,2,4,0.00000,76.00000,56.00000,
```

I am unable to rectify the error. How to overcome the warning in the 26th line? How can one solve this error?

Update :
when I try the same thing in different way like reading dataset from file instead of converting to dataframes, I am not getting the error. What would be the reason for that? The code is :

```
    weather_filename = 'wether.csv'
weather_file = open(weather_filename)
weather_data = weather_file.read()
weather_file.close()

# Break the weather records into lines
lines = weather_data.split('\n')
labels = lines[0]
values = lines[1:]
n_values = len(values)

# Break the list of comma-separated value strings
# into lists of values.
year = []
month = []
day = []
max_temp = []
j_year = 1
j_month = 2
j_day = 3
j_max_temp = 5

for i_row in range(n_values):
    split_values = values[i_row].split(',')
    if len(split_values) >= j_max_temp:
        year.append(int(split_values[j_year]))
        month.append(int(split_values[j_month]))
        day.append(int(split_values[j_day]))
        max_temp.append(float(split_values[j_max_temp]))

# Isolate the recent data.
i_mid = len(max_temp) // 2
temps = np.array(max_temp[i_mid:])
year = year[i_mid:]
month = month[i_mid:]
day = day[i_mid:]
temps[np.where(temps == -99.9)] = np.nan

# Remove all the nans.
# Trim both ends and fill nans in the middle.
# Find the first non-nan.
i_start = np.where(np.logical_not(np.isnan(temps)))[0][0]
temps = temps[i_start:]
year = year[i_start:]
month = month[i_start:]
day = day[i_start:]
i_nans = np.where(np.isnan(temps))[0]
print(i_nans)
```

What is wrong in the first code and why the second doesn't even give a warning?

Comment: Please provide some or all of `wether_list` - it looks like there is at least one element in `temps` which cannot be checked for `isnan()`.  For example, you can reproduce this issue with `np.isnan(np.array(["a",2,3]))`, where `"a"` is an invalid argument to `isnan()`.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but you do not need indices to select elements from a numpy array using a condition. `x[np.where(array([True,False,True]))]` for example is entirely equivalent to `x[array([True,False,True])]`. I'm just saying you can do the same task without the `np.where` using boolean masks. You could write for example `temps[temps == -99.9] = np.nan`

Comment: I have added dataset. Please look into that.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50588722/1548275. It has similar problem and has a solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What's the `dtype` of `temps`.  I can reproduce your warning and error with a string dtype:

```
In [26]: temps = np.array([1,2,'string',0])
In [27]: temps
Out[27]: array(['1', '2', 'string', '0'], dtype='<U21')
In [28]: temps==-99.9
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[28]: False
In [29]: np.isnan(temps)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-2ff7754ed926> in <module>()
----> 1 np.isnan(temps)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

First, comparing strings with the number gives this future warning.

Second, testing for `nan` produces the error.

Note that given the `dtype`, the `nan` assignment assigns a string value, not a float (`np.nan` is a float).

```
In [30]: temps[-1] = np.nan
In [31]: temps
Out[31]: array(['1', '2', 'string', 'nan'], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: You haven't confirmed my guess, or added any information on `temps`.  Typically when debugging code you have too look at values within the run, not just the file you start with.

Comment: when i check the dtype of this array, it is showing as <U9.

Comment: Look at `df.dtypes`  And values in max_temp.

Answer (score 92):

Posting as it might help future users.

As correctly pointed out by others, np.isnan won't work for `object` or `string` dtypes. If you're using pandas, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000993/) you can directly use `pd.isnull`, which should work in your case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
var1 = ''
var2 = np.nan
>>> type(var1)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(var2)
<class 'float'>
>>> pd.isnull(var1)
False
>>> pd.isnull(var2)
True
```

Comment: Thank you. this is the answer. so much mess in terms null incompatibility.

Answer (score 38):

Try replacing `np.isnan` with `pd.isna`. Pandas' `isna` supports category dtypes

Comment: Sorry, it does NOT work as intended: it does not distinguish `np.nan` or 'nan' from other, more innocent objects:
`assert pd.isna(str(np.nan));`
# 
`assert pd.isna('nan');`

Comment: Those examples are not nan - they are strings. The question is how do you find fields containing nan.

Answer (score 3):

`isnan(ndarray)` fails on ndarray dtype of "object"

`isnan(ndarray.astype(np.float))`, but strings cannot be coerced to float.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a result of an unwanted float to string conversion. To repair it, just reverse it by adding string-to-float conversion (assuming data is convertible to a number) using `float` or `np.float64`:

```
np.isnan(float(str(np.nan)))
True
```

or

```
np.isnan(float(str("nan")))
True
```

rather than:

```
np.isnan(str(np.nan))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [164], line 1
----> 1 np.isnan(str(np.nan))

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

---

Note that if your data is NOT convertible to numbers (floats), you need to use a string-compatible function such as `pd.isna` instead of `np.isnan`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error when trying to `transform` my dataset using [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). The error was thrown by `_check_unknown` function defined in [`sklearn.utils._encode`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/_encode.py#L303).

This was caused by the fact that, at `transform` time, one of the columns to be transformed had a type `float64` as opposed to `object` - in my case an entire column was `NaN`.

The solution was to cast the dataframe to `object` type before invoking `transform`:

```
ohe.transform(data.astype("O"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: This answer is somewhat related to the title of the question because this error prompts when working with Decimal types.

I got the same error when considering `Decimal` type values. For some reason, one column of the `dataframe` I'm considering comes as decimal. For example, when calling `.unique()` on this column I got

```
[Decimal('0'), Decimal('95'), Decimal('38'), Decimal('25'),
 Decimal('42'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('18'), Decimal('22'), 
.....Decimal('220'), Decimal('724')]
```

As the traceback of the error showed me that it failed when calling some `numpy` function. I manage to reproduce the error by considering the `min` and `max`values of the above array

```
from decimal import Decimal

xmin, xmax = Decimal('0'), Decimal('724')
np.isnan([xmin, xmax])
```

it will prompt the error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The solution in this case was to cast all these values to `int`.

```
df.astype({col:int for col in desired_columns_to_convert})
```