# Issue detecting nan in for loop using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Why can't I detect the np.nan value in data using np.isnan() in the list comprehension below? Does the list comprehension transform the type of values in some way?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a', 'b', np.nan]})

[print('NaN') if np.isnan(i) else print('Not NaN') for i in data.col]
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will get into trouble using `np.isnan()` because of the mixed types in the column. From pandas' [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html)

> Because NaN is a float, a column of integers with even one missing values is cast to floating-point dtype (see Support for integer NA for more)

Therefore you should consider, as @saeedghadiri suggested using `pd.isna()`:

```
[print('NaN') if pd.isna(i) else print('Not NaN') for i in data.col]
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look closer to your code, col as 3 values, `'a'`, `'b'` and `np.nan`. The two first are strings, the third is a np.float.

However, `np.isnan` is not designed for string types, then it will crash. The following will work

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1, 2, np.nan]})

[print('NaN') if np.isnan(i) else print('Not NaN') for i in data.col]
```

If you want to distinguish `np.nan` from all object types, you should use `pd.isna` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `pd.isna` everytime for checking nans. So your code changes to:

```
[print('NaN') if pd.isna(i) else print('Not NaN') for i in data.col]
```

The output would be:

```
Not NaN
Not NaN
NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71226861/8228122), you have to use `pd.isnull(i)` instead of `np.isnan(i)`, because the function `np.isnan()` doesn't work for `str` type.

```
[print('NaN') if pd.isnull(i) else print('Not NaN') for i in data.col]
```