# Compare two DataFrames and find missing timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1=

   date                col1
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 100
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 120
2  2023-01-01 16:30:00 140
3  2023-01-01 16:45:00 160
4  2023-01-01 17:00:00 200
5  2023-01-01 17:15:00 430
6  2023-01-01 17:30:00 890

df2 =

   date                col2 col3 
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 100  200
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 120  400
2  2023-01-01 17:00:00 200  500
```

and in `df2` I have some missing timestamps compared to `df1`. I am able to find those timestamps using the following code:

```
df1[~df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]
```

I want to populate those missing timestamps in `df2` and fill in the values of the columns with the average value of the two previous rows.

So the new `df2` should look like this:

```
df2 =

   date                col2    col3 
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 100     200
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 120     400
2  2023-01-01 16:30:00 110     300
3  2023-01-01 16:45:00 115     350
4  2023-01-01 17:00:00 200     500
5  2023-01-01 17:15:00 257.5   425
6  2023-01-01 17:30:00 228.75  462.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ideal solution via iteration:

```py
df1 = [
    ['2023-01-01 16:00:00', 100],
    ['2023-01-01 16:15:00', 120],
    ['2023-01-01 16:30:00', 140],
    ['2023-01-01 16:45:00', 160],
    ['2023-01-01 17:00:00', 200],
    ['2023-01-01 17:15:00', 430],
    ['2023-01-01 17:30:00', 890],
]

df2 = [
    ['2023-01-01 16:00:00', 100,  200],
    ['2023-01-01 16:15:00', 120,  400],
    ['2023-01-01 17:00:00', 200,  500],
]

df1= pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['date', 'col1'])

df2= pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = ['date', 'col2', 'col3'])

missing = df1[~df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]
missing = missing.drop(['col1'], axis=1)

merged = pd.concat([df2, missing])
merged.sort_values('date', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

for index, row in merged.iterrows():
    if np.isnan(row['col2']):
        merged['col2'].at[index] = merged['col2'].iloc[[index-1, index-2]].mean()
    if np.isnan(row['col3']):
        merged['col3'].at[index] = merged['col3'].iloc[[index-1, index-2]].mean()

print(merged)
```

Output:

| date | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 16:00:00 | 100.00 | 200.0 |
| 2023-01-01 16:15:00 | 120.00 | 400.0 |
| 2023-01-01 16:30:00 | 110.00 | 300.0 |
| 2023-01-01 16:45:00 | 115.00 | 350.0 |
| 2023-01-01 17:00:00 | 200.00 | 500.0 |
| 2023-01-01 17:15:00 | 157.50 | 425.0 |
| 2023-01-01 17:30:00 | 178.75 | 462.5 |

Comment: When I ran your code to the full Dataframe for the line `if np.isnan(row['fuell_cell']):` I am getting the following error `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`. Although I checked the types of my variables and they are `float64`.

Comment: @Pythoneer try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71226861/2501279) answer.

Comment: By replacing `np.isnan` with `pd.isnull` the issue was resolved. However, I cannot understand the cause of this error as my Dataframe did not contain any `object` or `string` dtypes.