# ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, arima

I am trying to train some machine learning models to predict the price action for 4 chosen stocks from a list of NASDAQ-100 stocks.

I am very new to Python, so I've run into a few issues I have not been able to fix. The first has been while trying to use the ARIMA model. I get the following error upon executing my code:

`None if faux_endog else np.any(np.isnan(self.endog))) TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

I have already tried using `dropna()`, `fillna()` and `isna()` to find/remove NaN or NULL values. Therefore there should be none left.

This is my code:

```
# Imports
import os
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from PIL import Image
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import math
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf

# Chosen stocks from NASDAQ-100
chosen_stocks = ['CTSH', 'BKNG', 'REGN', 'MSFT']

def get_data():
    # Get list of tickers
    tickers = open("dataset/nasdaq_100_tickers.txt", "r")
    data = tickers.read().splitlines()

    # Check if the data has already been downloaded, drop NaN values
    if os.path.exists('dataframe.csv'):
        dataframe = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', index_col="Date", parse_dates=True).dropna()
    else:
        # Download Close data from Yahoo Finance
        data = yf.download(tickers=data, period='1y', interval='1d')['Close']
        data.to_csv('dataframe.csv')
        # Convert array to Pandas dataframe, drop NaN values
        complete_data = data.dropna()
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(complete_data)
    dataframe.drop(['GEHC'], axis=1, inplace=True) # Dropping GEHC because it contains NULL values

    return dataframe



def arima_prediction(stock):
    train_data, test_data = stock[3:int(len(dataframe) * 0.5)], stock[int(len(dataframe) * 0.5):]
    train_arima = train_data
    test_arima = test_data

    history = [x for x in train_arima]
    y = test_arima
    predictions = list()
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1, 1, 0))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    forecast = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    predictions.append(forecast)
    history.append(y[0])

    for i in range(1, len(y)):
        # Predict
        model = ARIMA(history, order=(1, 1, 0))
        model_fit = model.fit()
        forecast = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        # Invert transformed prediction
        predictions.append(forecast)
        # Observation
        observation = y[i]
        history.append(observation)

    # Report performance
    mean_squared = mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
    print('Mean Squared Error: ' + str(mean_squared))
    mean_absolute = mean_absolute_error(y, predictions)
    print('Mean Absolute Error: ' + str(mean_absolute))
    root_mean_squared = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, predictions))
    print('Root Mean Squared Error: ' + str(root_mean_squared))

dataframe = get_data()
for stock in chosen_stocks:
    arima_prediction(stock)
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                  AAPL        ABNB  ...         ZM          ZS
Date                                ...                       
2022-12-15  136.500000   90.610001  ...  70.199997  117.169998
2022-12-16  134.509995   89.570000  ...  69.860001  114.209999
2022-12-19  132.369995   85.930000  ...  69.089996  112.269997
2022-12-20  132.300003   87.620003  ...  68.559998  113.540001
2022-12-21  135.449997   87.070000  ...  69.930000  112.769997
...                ...         ...  ...        ...         ...
2023-11-28  190.399994  127.559998  ...  67.529999  193.850006
2023-11-29  189.369995  126.480003  ...  67.949997  199.839996
2023-11-30  189.949997  126.339996  ...  67.830002  197.529999
2023-12-01  191.240005  135.020004  ...  70.290001  198.029999
2023-12-04  188.669998  134.539993  ...  67.720001  197.919998
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/source/repos/Project/main.py", line 370, in <module>
    arima_prediction(stock)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/source/repos/Project/main.py", line 217, in arima_prediction
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1, 1, 0))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima\model.py", line 158, in __init__
    self._spec_arima = SARIMAXSpecification(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima\specification.py", line 458, in __init__
    None if faux_endog else np.any(np.isnan(self.endog)))
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback, including which line triggered the error?

Comment: @NickODell I've added the full traceback to the post. It is triggered from line 458 in `C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima\specification.py: __init__`, which is called by line 217 in my `main.py`.

Comment: When you call `arima_prediction`, the parameter you're passing is a string (the stock symbol).  Your code seems to expect it to be a dataframe.  You seem to have skipped a lookup.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you might be having issues with [object dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657223/typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported-for-the-input-types-and-the-inputs-could). Do you mind printing out the value of the `history` variable, right before `model = ARIMA(history, order=(1, 1, 0))` ?

Comment: @NickODell `history` is printed as `['H']`, I'm not too sure if this is what it's meant to be.

Comment: That represents a list with one string in it. Given that you're fitting an ARIMA model, and ARIMA is meant to work on numbers and not strings, I think it's definitely not right.

Comment: @NickODell I did originally try converting the values in the dataframe to float by using `dataframe = dataframe[stock].astype(float)` and `dataframe = pd.to_numeric(dataframe[stock])`, have I done this incorrectly?

Comment: Those steps look reasonable to me. I think Tim Roberts has the right idea - the variable passed to `arima_prediction` is a string, but it indexes into it as if its a dataframe.

Comment: @NickODell I apologise if this is a silly question, but what do you mean by lookup, and how to do I do the lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was being caused by the stock not being passed in properly, as commenters suggested.

Therefore in order to make sure the stocks were passed in properly instead of as a string, instead of passing in the stock by:

```
for stock in chosen_stocks:
    arima_prediction(stock)
```

I've instead used:

```
def get_stock_data(dataframe):
    get_stock_data = dataframe.iloc[:, 30]
    return get_stock_data

stock_data = get_stock_data(dataframe)
arima_prediction(stock_data)
```

Thank you to everyone for your help!